# What should the order of date and place of a meeting be?

Tags: word-order

Which of these two sentences is correct?

> The Ninth Session of the ABC Committee was held from 16 to 18 January 2022 in Madrid, Spain.
>
> The Ninth Session of the ABC Committee was held in Madrid, Spain, from 16 to 18 January 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Both work for me.

If you want a rule-of-thumb to follow, a common one is the [5 Ws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws), commonly presented as:

> *Who, What, When, Where, Why*

or sometimes as

> *Who, What, Where, When, Why*

possibly followed by *How*. This helps people who are skim-reading to decide whether to look in more detail, and you may find other orders used.

Such an order is not obligatory, but it puts the filterable items earlier: in your case, you might want to judge whether  people are more likely to decide to continue or stop reading because it happened in Madrid or because it happened in January 2022?

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, Henry, especially on the 5Ws! I'm copyediting a paper and wanted to change the order to show the date first, but now I'll just keep the author's original phrase.